# Java Thread communication with other programms

Tags: java, multithreading, flash

I have following problem:

I have a flash movie player, that also captures keyboard input and mousemovement. I need to pass this input informations to a java application on server side, that runs several Threads. Every Thread handels a specific flash movie player/clients input.

How could i establish this communication between the Flash client and its specific Thread?
Is there a better way than using Sockets?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for servlets! You can setup a servlet container on the server (Tomcat/Jetty,etc.) and each servlet can spin up HTTP sessions with the respective flash clients for tracking. The difference is that you would need to communicate from flash via HTTP instead of sockets but you could actually write a raw socket servlet and/or create your own socket protocol with a little more effort.